Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX201 160MHz low link speed (slow speed - uses MIMO 1x1 @80Mhz only it seems)
I have a PC with an ASUS Rogstrix Z690 Gaming WIFI-D4 motherboard which comes with an Intel Ax201 160MHz wireless module.
Since I've upgraded my internet subscription to a 1Gbs fiber connection, I noticed my PC, links poorly to my router and therefore I get an extremely poor connection speed despite having a 1Gbps fiber connection.
Like instead of getting  866.6Mbs (because router is WiFi5 (supports 802.11ac) it only gets anything from 26 Mbs to at most 433.3 Mbs! and rarely (only once in the past 4 weeks, 650Mbs which quickly went down to 290Mbs!) and even that is not stable and fluctuates constantly!
My phone which uses a cheap WiFi-5 wcn3990 chip, can link 866.6Mhz 30 feet away, but my PC can't even link no where near that number literally adjacent to the router!(and I mean literally literally!)
Here is my PC in my room 24 feet away (router is in the other room)(today - the PC power setting is set at Performance):

(base) hossein@hossein-pc:~$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp5s0    no wireless extensions.

wlo1      IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Unknown-F5"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.745 GHz  Access Point: F0:2F:A7:F0:CA:69   
          Bit Rate=351 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=60/70  Signal level=-50 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:11   Missed beacon:0

virbr0    no wireless extensions.

docker0   no wireless extensions.

When the PC is in balanced mode (this is a few days ago):
-pc:~$ iwconfig
lo no wireless extensions.

enp5s0 no wireless extensions.

wlo1 IEEE 802.11 ESSID:"Unknown-F5"
Mode:Managed Frequency:5.745 GHz Access Point: F0:2F:A7:F0:CA:69
Bit Rate=260 Mb/s Tx-Power=22 dBm
Retry short limit:7 RTS thr:off Fragment thr:off
Power Management:on
Link Quality=54/70 Signal level=-56 dBm
Rx invalid nwid:0 Rx invalid crypt:0 Rx invalid frag:0
Tx excessive retries:0 Invalid misc:6 Missed beacon:0

virbr0 no wireless extensions.

docker0 no wireless extensions.


Taking the PC to the other room and placing it next to the router doesn't change anything despite having a prefect link quality(70/70), signal level (-25 db), it got me a bit-rate of 433.33MHz! only.

-pc:~$ iwconfig
lo no wireless extensions.

enp5s0 no wireless extensions.

wlo1 IEEE 802.11 ESSID:"Unknown-F5"
Mode:Managed Frequency:5.745 GHz Access Point: F0:2F:A7:F0:CA:69
Bit Rate=433.33 Mb/s Tx-Power=22 dBm
Retry short limit:7 RTS thr:off Fragment thr:off
Power Management:on
Link Quality=70/70 Signal level=-25 dBm
Rx invalid nwid:0 Rx invalid crypt:0 Rx invalid frag:0
Tx excessive retries:0 Invalid misc:6 Missed beacon:0

virbr0 no wireless extensions.

docker0 no wireless extensions.


It seems its only working at 1x1 MIMO! instead of 2x2 MIMO at 80Mhz channel! (with MCS Modulation 256 QAM and encoding 5/6)

My Router is a 4x4 MIMO Hawei EG8245W5 GPON Terminal and I believe my motherboards WiFi chip, Intel AX201 160MHz, to also be a 2x2 MIMO module. so it should be able to properly link and achieve a decent and stable connection but it doesn't.
Side-note:
I have seen a lot of posts about this specific module on Ubuntu, but none of them really helped, as many were for previous versions of Ubuntu dating a few years back, so I decided to ask a new question. I gathered the information some of those previous questions had posted, and tried some of the ways they were told to try and wrote their results below.
Please kindly tell me if I posted this in the wrong section, since there were already similar questions, I decided to post it here (I was skeptical to whether post this on superuser site or here)

I tried booting a 24.04.1 live cd to see if the new version fixes this or not, it doesn't! could it be because we are using the same kernel version? (I'm using 6.8 and I believe 24.04.1 is also on 6.8)

I also tried sudo apt install firmware-iwlwifi to no avail, that package doesn't exist in 22.04 it seems.

I also tried  sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-22.04 nothing changed.

I also disabled the power save by setting:
wifi.powersave = 2 in /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf and also set the ubuntu to Performance mode (from settings dropdown menu) but nothing changed.

I also tried updating the firmware, but it seems nothing changed for some reason, either I did something wrong, or I failed to do more needed stps.
What I did was to :


git clone https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/
cd linux-firmware/
sudo cp iwlwifi-*.ucode /lib/firmware
sudo update-initramfs -u
sudo reboot



but nothing changed after reboot (I noticed the drivers werent updated as the output of sudo lshw -C network showed the firmware was still the same!)
Here is the output of Wireless Info Script : https://pastebin.com/FkL6nwcK
Here are a few outputs that might be useful:

uname -a

Linux hossein-pc 6.8.0-40-generic #40~22.04.3-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Jul 30 17:30:19 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux



(base) hossein@hossein-pc:~$ lspci | grep -i network
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 7af0 (rev 11)



(base) hossein@hossein-pc:~$ modinfo iwlwifi
filename: /lib/modules/6.8.0-40-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license: GPL
description: Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
firmware: iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-6000g2a-6.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-6000-6.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-7265D-29.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-7265-17.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-3168-29.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-3160-17.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-7260-17.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-8265-36.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-8000C-36.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-cc-a0-77.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-jf-b0-77.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-77.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-Qu-b0-jf-b0-77.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-Qu-c0-hr-b0-77.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-Qu-b0-hr-b0-77.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-ma-b0-gf4-a0.pnvm
firmware: iwlwifi-ma-b0-gf-a0.pnvm
firmware: iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0.pnvm
firmware: iwlwifi-so-a0-gf4-a0.pnvm
firmware: iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0.pnvm
firmware: iwlwifi-ma-b0-mr-a0-86.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-ma-b0-gf4-a0-86.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-ma-b0-gf-a0-86.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-ma-b0-hr-b0-86.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-ma-a0-mr-a0-86.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-ma-a0-gf4-a0-86.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-ma-a0-gf-a0-86.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-ma-a0-hr-b0-86.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-86.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-so-a0-gf-a0-86.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-86.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-so-a0-jf-b0-86.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-gl-c0-fm-c0.pnvm
firmware: iwlwifi-gl-c0-fm-c0-86.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-gl-b0-fm-b0-86.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-bz-a0-fm4-b0-86.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-bz-a0-fm-c0-86.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-bz-a0-fm-b0-86.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-bz-a0-gf4-a0-86.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-bz-a0-gf-a0-86.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-bz-a0-hr-b0-86.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-sc2f-a0-wh-a0-86.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-sc2f-a0-fm-c0-86.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-sc2-a0-wh-a0-86.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-sc2-a0-fm-c0-86.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-sc-a0-wh-a0-86.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-sc-a0-gf4-a0-86.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-sc-a0-gf-a0-86.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-sc-a0-hr-b0-86.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-sc-a0-hr-b0-86.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-sc-a0-fm-c0-86.ucode
firmware: iwlwifi-sc-a0-fm-b0-86.ucode
srcversion: 5C64393722CF59087AFEA69
....
parm: swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm: 11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
parm: amsdu_size:amsdu size 0: 12K for multi Rx queue devices, 2K for AX210 devices, 4K for other devices 1:4K 2:8K 3:12K (16K buffers) 4: 2K (default 0) (int)
parm: fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
parm: nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
parm: uapsd_disable:disable U-APSD functionality bitmap 1: BSS 2: P2P Client (default: 3) (uint)
parm: enable_ini:0:disable, 1-15:FW_DBG_PRESET Values, 16:enabled without preset value defined,Debug INI TLV FW debug infrastructure (default: 16) (uint)
parm: bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm: led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
parm: power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm: power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)
parm: disable_11ac:Disable VHT capabilities (default: false) (bool)
parm: remove_when_gone:Remove dev from PCIe bus if it is deemed inaccessible (default: false) (bool)
parm: disable_11ax:Disable HE capabilities (default: false) (bool)
parm: disable_11be:Disable EHT capabilities (default: false) (bool)



(base) hossein@hossein-pc:~$ sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] password for hossein:
*-network
description: Wireless interface
product: Intel Corporation
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 14.3
bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
logical name: wlo1
version: 11
serial: a0:d5:0b:92:2c:0e
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=6.8.0-40-generic firmware=86.fb5c9aeb.0 so-a0-hr-b0-86.uc ip=192.168.100.19 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
resources: iomemory:440-43f irq:18 memory:4406224000-4406227fff
*-network
description: Ethernet interface
product: Ethernet Controller I225-V
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
logical name: enp5s0
version: 03
serial: 0b:a2:10:31:62:51
capacity: 1Gbit/s
width: 32 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igc driverversion=6.8.0-40-generic firmware=1073:8754 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
resources: irq:19 memory:86500000-865fffff memory:86600000-86603fff



>> sudo dmesg | grep iw
[ 5.386751] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[ 5.389105] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected crf-id 0x1300504, cnv-id 0x80401 wfpm id 0x80000030
[ 5.389128] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: PCI dev 7af0/0074, rev=0x430, rfid=0x10a100
[ 5.395775] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 0.0.2.41
[ 5.396358] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 86.fb5c9aeb.0 so-a0-hr-b0-86.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[ 5.477608] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX201 160MHz, REV=0x430
[ 5.486116] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Invalid buffer destination
[ 5.586254] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WFPM_UMAC_PD_NOTIFICATION: 0x20
[ 5.586283] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WFPM_LMAC2_PD_NOTIFICATION: 0x1f
[ 5.586291] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WFPM_AUTH_KEY_0: 0x90
[ 5.586300] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: CNVI_SCU_SEQ_DATA_DW9: 0x10
[ 5.586375] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected RF HR B5, rfid=0x10a100
[ 5.587313] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: RFIm is deactivated, reason = 5
[ 5.652666] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: base HW address: a0:d5:0b:92:2c:0e
[ 5.684274] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3 wlo1: renamed from wlan0
[ 7.399440] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Invalid buffer destination
[ 7.498728] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WFPM_UMAC_PD_NOTIFICATION: 0x20
[ 7.498756] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WFPM_LMAC2_PD_NOTIFICATION: 0x1f
[ 7.498765] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WFPM_AUTH_KEY_0: 0x90
[ 7.498774] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: CNVI_SCU_SEQ_DATA_DW9: 0x10
[ 7.499815] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: RFIm is deactivated, reason = 5
[ 7.567394] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Registered PHC clock: iwlwifi-PTP, with index: 1
[ 26.562291] warning: `iwconfig' uses wireless extensions which will stop working for Wi-Fi 7 hardware; use nl80211


(base) hossein@hossein-pc:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 4668 (rev 02)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 12th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller #1 (rev 02)
00:0a.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Platform Monitoring Technology (rev 01)
00:0e.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation Volume Management Device NVMe RAID Controller
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 7ae0 (rev 11)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Device 7aa7 (rev 11)
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 7af0 (rev 11)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Device 7acc (rev 11)
00:15.1 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Device 7acd (rev 11)
00:15.2 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Device 7ace (rev 11)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device 7ae8 (rev 11)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device 7ae2 (rev 11)
00:1a.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 7ac8 (rev 11)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 7ab8 (rev 11)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 7ab9 (rev 11)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 7abb (rev 11)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 7ab4 (rev 11)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 7a84 (rev 11)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 7ad0 (rev 11)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device 7aa3 (rev 11)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Device 7aa4 (rev 11)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GA102 [GeForce RTX 3080] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GA102 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
04:00.0 SATA controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1062 Serial ATA Controller (rev 02)
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Controller I225-V (rev 03)
06:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller 980
(base) hossein@hossein-pc:~$ 


(base) hossein@hossein-pc:~$ rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no



do you mean setting /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf? yes I have set it to wifi.powersave = 2 which I believe means no powersaving.

Thanks alot really appreciate it, I did that as well, but haven't updated the other two logs (the first one belongs to today and has the powermanagement off, but the other two from a few days ago had them on because I hadnt meddled with the powermanagement at the time. regardless, now that the powermanagement/power saving is off, it still acts the same way.

Go into router settings and change encryption to WPA2 only without TKIP, TKIP may be causing an issue

The encryption had a separate option, it was set to TKIP+AES, I changed it to AES only, but that didnt change anything, it still links lower (i.e. 390/433/260Mbs).

Are there any results for sudo dmesg | grep iwl

yes, here they are : https://pastebin.com/c2e7yQtE

It might be worth renaming some intel firmware files in /lib/firmware, you are currently using iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-86.ucode.zst, you could rename that to iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-86.ucode.zst.bak then reboot and see if it is any different, there are 8 or so iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0 files in that directory, hopefully one of them fixes the speed

Thanks a lot @Jeremy31, really appreciate your kind help.I'll try that and report back

It didnt solve the issue, the problem still persists
